# Equal spacing between two columns inside a table element

Tags: html, css, html-table, multiple-columns

```css
table {
width:100%;
}
td {
padding:15px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>100</td>
    <td>20A long text</td>
    <td>300</td>
    <td>300</td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>400</td>
    <td>500</td>
    <td>600</td>
    <td>300</td>

  </tr>
</table>
```

The content of the cell can be of varied length and the cell width will be according to the content. It must look something like this

|---Text1---|---A very long text---|---Text 3---|

But this is how it looks like now

|--Text1--|-----A very long text-----|--Text 3--|

To reiterate, I am not expecting an equal length cell width, but equal spacing between columns.

Comment: Can you please provide the HTML codes you used? You can use padding & width CSS to control the layout.

Comment: post your code here

Comment: I have added code. Please check .

Comment: I think you mean the table should look as if all the cells have the same padding, right? Then you should delete the second row from your example, because it confuses things.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, I don't know of a way to do this in pure CSS.
As a workaround, you can use JavaScript to calculate the width each table cell needs to have in order to reach 100% width.

How's this to start off to? Note that I changed the CSS to set the horizontal padding to 0 (this is necessary, otherwise you'll have to incorporate the computed padding in the JS calculation); and I gave the cells borders (this is *not* necessary, but it demonstrates the required results better).

```js
let tbl = document.getElementById('tbl');
tbl.style.width = 'auto';
let extraSpace = document.body.clientWidth - tbl.offsetWidth;
let cols = tbl.rows[0].cells.length;
for (i = 0; i<cols; ++i) {
  let padding = Math.round(extraSpace/(cols-i));
  let cell = tbl.rows[0].cells[i];
  cell.style.width = (cell.clientWidth + padding) + 'px';
  extraSpace -= padding;
}
```

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
}

td {
  padding: 15px 0;
  text-align: center;
  border:1px dotted gray;
}
```

```html
<table id="tbl">
  <tr>
    <td>100</td>
    <td>20A long text</td>
    <td>300</td>
    <td>300</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>400</td>
    <td>500</td>
    <td>600</td>
    <td>300</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the `width:100%` the columns will stretch to fit the content, with an equal 15px of padding between. At the moment the width of 100% is causing the table to redistribute the available space automatically to fill the screen's width.

Comment: But I'd like the table to take up the complete width of the parent container.

Comment: Then it's impossible to have the exact same gap between the cells as you've outlined, because the table cells will always be different width depending on the content inside them. You could try adding a width the cells, but I don't think it will achieve the effect you're after.

Comment: @CKA Can you use JavaScript? Then draw the table first, see how wide it is and calculate how much more padding the cells need to get the table up to 100%.

Comment: Would you be able to provide a code sample as to how this can be achieved using javascript? @MrLister

Comment: @AlxTheRed The requirement from the product is to have equal spacing between columns. Not sure how else to achieve this.

Comment: @CKA Like I said, the only way to do it would be to _not_ have a 100% width table. Or as Mr Lister has said, use JavaScript. I believe he's suggesting you use the JS to determine how much padding to apply, rather than use a pre-determined pixel size.

Comment: I'd really appreciate it if you could post a code snippet as to how it can be achieved using javascript? @AlxTheRed

Comment: @CKA This isn't my code, but is it what you're trying to achieve? https://codepen.io/AllThingsSmitty/pen/jALALm ... I'm not sure it is.

Comment: This demonstrates equal width which is not what I am trying to achieve as the spacing between columns wouldn't be the same. I have forked it and you can see it here https://codepen.io/praneethack/pen/bZKrpY @AlxTheRed

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought. What you're trying to do goes against how HTML works, so it's quite complicated to do, and I'm not convinced it's worth the effort. We will have to see if @MrLister has a solution in JS.

Answer (score 0):

Using CSS, you can set `padding-left` and `padding-right` for the `<td>` and `<th>` elements, to set spacing between columns.

```css
td, th {
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>1st cell</th>
    <th>2nd cell</th>
    <th>3rd cell</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1st cell content</td>
    <td>2nd cell content</td>
    <td>3rd cell content</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: The issue is when the width of the table is 100%, cannot achieve the desired effect. The table's width needs to as big the enclosing container.

Answer (score -1):

Please, for next questions kindly provide your code.
You can add CSS properties **table-layout: fixed;** to table tag
fixed properties: *Sets a fixed table layout algorithm. The table and column widths are set by the widths of table and col or by the width of the first row of cells. Cells in other rows do not affect column widths. If no widths are present on the first row, the column widths are divided equally across the table, regardless of content inside the cells*
Moreover you can set a fixed **padding** (left and right) to cells in order to have a left and right fixed withespaces
Here is an example

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">

        .tab-cell {
            padding-left: 20px;
            padding-right:  20px;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <table style="table-layout: fixed; text-align: center;" border="1">
        <tr>
            <th class = "tab-cell">Column A</th>
            <th class = "tab-cell">Column B</th>
            <th class = "tab-cell">Column C</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th class = "tab-cell">some content</th>
            <th class = "tab-cell">some looooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong content</th>
            <th class = "tab-cell">some content</th>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

---

Result
[image]

---

Hope it helps.
**Hele**

Comment: As I have mentioned in the question, I am not looking for an equal width. Even if the width is equal, the spacing between columns will not be even, which is not the expected behaviour.

Comment: My code will not create a table with equal width cells (infact column 2 is larger than 1 and 3), but, as you asked, an equal spacing between columns